# how to create multiple application in one react native project

Tags: react-native

I want to create two different applications in 1 react native project that shares some common UI components. Consider below example
These are common components

1. Home
2. Option1, Option2 etc

In App1 the flow is
Home -> Option1 -> App1's Specific component

In App2 the flow is
Home -> Option1 -> App2's Specific component

How to achieve this scenario? Thanks in advance